# Connection to remote farm does not work

Tags: 2013

From what I read here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453293.aspx) it should be possible to connect to a remote farm. Unfortunately my program simply refuses to use the remote DB server even though I'm providing it explicitly in the connection string as you can in the following example.

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder vBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
vBuilder.DataSource = @"REMOTEDBSERVER\SP2013";            
vBuilder.InitialCatalog = @"SharePoint_ConfigDB";
vBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
SPFarm vFarm = SPFarm.Open(vBuilder.ToString());
```

When I try to run this a sql exception is thrown.

```
{"Cannot open database \"SharePoint_ConfigDB\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'DOMAIN\\farmAdmin'."}
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing or is it simply not possible to do this with SharePoint 2013?

I'm trying to do this from a machine which is in the same domain as the remote DB server and I'm logged in as the farm. Using the SQL Server Management Studio I have no problem to connect to the remote DB from this machine.

Thanks in advance.